# Moving data from datatable to datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a C# program that selects data from two different database files and combines the data that I need into a datatable (dt).  All the information I need is in that datatable, and I want to put it into a datagridview.  Besides the information in the datatable, I also have two columns in the datagridview that I'll calculate as I add each row to the datagridview (dataGridView1).

My question is: How can I get my datatable (dt) into the datagridview (dataGridView1)?  Would I do something like this?:

```
dataGridView1.column("MemberSep") = dt.column("MBRNUM);
```

I'm thinking that I could loop through the datatable, calculate the values for my first two columns of the datagridview, and then write it all to a row until I've read the whole datatable.  I've never worked with a datagridview control before.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Picture of my App]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set the DataGridView's `DataSource` to the `DataTable`.

Comment: I see the property for DataSource, and the dialog to add project data source.  But, when I try this, I do not see where to choose my datatable from.  I'm not familiar with this action (choosing a datasource) so I may be missing a step.

Comment: +1.  Just keep it simple.  And perform your queries so that the column title you want is the actual name of the column.  For example, "Select MBRNUM ASMemberSep..."

Comment: Oh, so I can just say "dataGridView1.DataSouce = dt" in my program?

Comment: @Kevin - you do it via code `this.myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable`

Comment: There are tons of videos here as well to help you out: http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx

Comment: @David, thanks!  That's a good idea about keeping it simple.  I'll modify my select statement so that the column title is the actual name of the column in question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use data binding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
//add in tables
table.Columns.Add("Column 1", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Column 2", typeof(int));
//add in rows
table.Rows.Add(1, 2);
```

This would just mean iterating through the dbf's and grabbing the column names then inserting them with 2 for each (column) loops, then add in your custom columns you need. Also could drop any linking columns that are identical in each column.

Then 2 more for each (row) loops and you can populate the data rows.

All that is left is a for each row in table to calculate the custom column values for that row.

Depending on the relationships of the dbf's you can just tweak the loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually fill datagridview I suggest to use strong typed datatables and rows from Dataset. In this case you don't have to worry about column names.