# Newtonsoft Json Deserlize as C# Datagridview

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, json.net

I have some issues using the Newtonsoft Json Plugin. I want to fill a datagridview using Json but dont know how. In the Documentation of Newtonsoft Json i get an exmaple with datatable but if i try this sample i just get Errors.

This is my Json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "17",
        "name": "Filename",
        "author": "unknown",
        "size": "3.1MB",
        "pfad": "ftp://path/Filename",
        "Filetoken": "6747rzuzur6urzut766754677"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "name": "Filename",
        "author": "unknown",
        "size": "3.1MB",
        "pfad": "ftp://path/Filename",
        "Filetoken": "6747rzuzur6urzut766754677"
    }
]
```

I tried to use this [example](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDataSet.htm) and [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm)

Maybe anyone can help?

Comment: What code are you using to populate the DataGridView?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The difference in your JSON and the example is that the example deserializes an object with a Table property. Your JSON is an array. Can you wrap your JSON with `{ 'Table1': ..... }` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON is an array, not an object, so deserialize it as a `DataTable`:

```
var dataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

Then add the `DataTable` to the `DataGridView` using this answer: [Moving data from datatable to datagridview in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902269/moving-data-from-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if i try to do this i get a "Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object." Exception

Comment: @Sevenlive - I don't get this exception with the JSON you posted.  Is your actual JSON more complex than what you posted?