# deserialize woocommerce json product list in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I've got an serialized Json string from woocommerce product list , the question is how can i deserialize this string and put this on a list of product class which i have in my C#   , i have tried many searches on web but they were unsuccessful :|
and the second question is "is there anyway that i can have woocommerce product class ? "
thank you all <3

my string is :

```
[{"id":83,"name":"Woo Album #1","slug":"woo-album-1","permalink":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/product\/woo-album-1\/","date_created":"2013-06-07T16:03:05","date_created_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:33:05","date_modified":"2013-06-07T16:03:05","date_modified_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:33:05","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","short_description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","sku":"","price":"9","regular_price":"9","sale_price":"","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"price_html":"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>9.00<\/span>","on_sale":false,"purchasable":true,"total_sales":0,"virtual":false,"downloadable":true,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"0.00","rating_count":0,"related_ids":[67,37,70,50,19],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":36,"name":"Bags","slug":"bags"},{"id":37,"name":"Bags","slug":"bags-accessories"},{"id":42,"name":"Clothing","slug":"clothing-for-her"},{"id":44,"name":"Dresses","slug":"dresses"},{"id":47,"name":"Heels","slug":"heels"}],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":2368,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:25:59","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:55:59","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:25:59","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:55:59","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product1.jpg","name":"home_store_product1","alt":"","position":0},{"id":2369,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:26:07","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:56:07","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:26:07","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:56:07","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product1b.jpg","name":"home_store_product1b","alt":"","position":1},{"id":2371,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:28:26","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:26","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:28:26","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:26","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product2.jpg","name":"home_store_product2","alt":"","position":2},{"id":2370,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:28:16","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:16","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:28:16","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:16","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product2b.jpg","name":"home_store_product2b","alt":"","position":3}],"attributes":[],"default_attributes":[],"variations":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0,"meta_data":[{"id":1944,"key":"_vc_post_settings","value":{"vc_grid_id":[]}},{"id":2006,"key":"_download_type","value":""},{"id":2007,"key":"slide_template","value":""}],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products\/83"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products"}]}},{"id":79,"name":"Woo Logo","slug":"woo-logo-3","permalink":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/product\/woo-logo-3\/","date_created":"2013-06-07T15:59:44","date_created_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:29:44","date_modified":"2013-06-07T15:59:44","date_modified_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:29:44","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","short_description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","sku":"","price":"15","regular_price":"15","sale_price":"","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"price_html":"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>15.00<\/span>","on_sale":false,"purchasable":true,"total_sales":1,"virtual":false,"downloadable":false,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"0.00","rating_count":0,"related_ids":[53,19,34,60,40],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[15,60],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":38,"name":"Ballet pumps","slug":"ballet-pumps"},{"id":39,"name":"Belts","slug":"belts"},{"id":52,"name":"Jeans","slug":"jeans-clothing-for-her-for-him"},{"id":59,"name":"Shorts","slug":"shorts"},{"id":31,"name":"Slippers","slug":"slippers"}],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":2371,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:28:26","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:26","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:28:26","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:26","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product2.jpg","name":"home_store_product2","alt":"","position":0},{"id":2370,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:28:16","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:16","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:28:16","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:16","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product2b.jpg","name":"home_store_product2b","alt":"","position":1},{"id":2373,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:29:42","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:59:42","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:29:42","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:59:42","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product3b.jpg","name":"home_store_product3b","alt":"","position":2},{"id":2374,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:30:04","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:00:04","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:30:04","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:00:04","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product4b.jpg","name":"home_store_product4b","alt":"","position":3}],"attributes":[],"default_attributes":[],"variations":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0,"meta_data":[{"id":1884,"key":"_vc_post_settings","value":{"vc_grid_id":[]}},{"id":1940,"key":"slide_template","value":""}],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products\/79"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products"}]}},{"id":76,"name":"Woo Ninja","slug":"woo-ninja-3","permalink":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/product\/woo-ninja-3\/","date_created":"2013-06-07T15:58:45","date_created_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:28:45","date_modified":"2013-06-07T15:58:45","date_modified_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:28:45","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","short_description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","sku":"","price":"15","regular_price":"15","sale_price":"","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"price_html":"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>15.00<\/span>","on_sale":false,"purchasable":true,"total_sales":0,"virtual":false,"downloadable":false,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"4.00","rating_count":1,"related_ids":[19,67,73,15,56],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[34,47],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":45,"name":"Hats &amp; Caps","slug":"hats-caps"},{"id":46,"name":"Hats &amp; Caps","slug":"hats-caps-accessories"},{"id":49,"name":"Jackets","slug":"jackets"},{"id":61,"name":"Sunglasses","slug":"sunglasses-accessories-for-him"}],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":2379,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:37:59","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:07:59","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:37:59","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:07:59","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/03\/home_store_product3.jpg","name":"home_store_product3","alt":"","position":0},{"id":2373,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:29:42","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:59:42","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:29:42","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:59:42","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product3b.jpg","name":"home_store_product3b","alt":"","position":1},{"id":2378,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:35:06","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:05:06","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:35:06","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:05:06","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product5b.jpg","name":"home_store_product5b","alt":"","position":2},{"id":2374,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:30:04","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:00:04","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:30:04","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:00:04","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product4b.jpg","name":"home_store_product4b","alt":"","position":3}],"attributes":[],"default_attributes":[],"variations":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0,"meta_data":[{"id":1824,"key":"_vc_post_settings","value":{"vc_grid_id":[]}},{"id":1879,"key":"slide_template","value":""}],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products\/76"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products"}]}},{"id":73,"name":"Premium Quality","slug":"premium-quality-2","permalink":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/product\/premium-quality-2\/","date_created":"2013-06-07T15:57:38","date_created_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:27:38","date_modified":"2013-06-07T15:57:38","date_modified_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:27:38","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","short_description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","sku":"","price":"12","regular_price":"15","sale_price":"12","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"price_html":"<del><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>15.00<\/span><\/del> <ins><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>12.00<\/span><\/ins>","on_sale":true,"purchasable":true,"total_sales":2,"virtual":false,"downloadable":false,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"2.00","rating_count":2,"related_ids":[56,22,67,76,40],"upsell_ids":[19],"cross_sell_ids":[],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":35,"name":"Ankle boots","slug":"ankle-boots"},{"id":56,"name":"Rucksacks","slug":"rucksacks-accessories"},{"id":61,"name":"Sunglasses","slug":"sunglasses-accessories-for-him"},{"id":62,"name":"T-shirts","slug":"t-shirts"}],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":2375,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:30:13","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:00:13","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:30:13","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:00:13","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product4.jpg","name":"home_store_product4","alt":"","position":0},{"id":2374,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:30:04","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:00:04","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:30:04","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:00:04","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product4b.jpg","name":"home_store_product4b","alt":"","position":1},{"id":2370,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:28:16","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:16","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:28:16","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:16","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product2b.jpg","name":"home_store_product2b","alt":"","position":2}],"attributes":[],"default_attributes":[],"variations":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0,"meta_data":[{"id":1764,"key":"_vc_post_settings","value":{"vc_grid_id":[]}},{"id":1820,"key":"slide_template","value":""}],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products\/73"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products"}]}},{"id":70,"name":"Flying Ninja","slug":"flying-ninja","permalink":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/product\/flying-ninja\/","date_created":"2013-06-07T15:55:01","date_created_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:25:01","date_modified":"2013-06-07T15:55:01","date_modified_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:25:01","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","short_description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","sku":"","price":"12","regular_price":"15","sale_price":"12","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"price_html":"<del><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>15.00<\/span><\/del> <ins><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>12.00<\/span><\/ins>","on_sale":true,"purchasable":true,"total_sales":4,"virtual":false,"downloadable":false,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"4.00","rating_count":4,"related_ids":[79,19,47,34,31],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":44,"name":"Dresses","slug":"dresses"},{"id":51,"name":"Jeans","slug":"jeans"},{"id":53,"name":"Moccasins","slug":"moccasins"},{"id":58,"name":"Sandals","slug":"sandals-shoes"},{"id":59,"name":"Shorts","slug":"shorts"},{"id":60,"name":"Sunglasses","slug":"sunglasses"},{"id":64,"name":"Trousers","slug":"trousers"}],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":2377,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:34:06","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:04:06","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:34:06","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:04:06","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product5.jpg","name":"home_store_product5","alt":"","position":0},{"id":2378,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:35:06","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:05:06","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:35:06","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:05:06","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product5b.jpg","name":"home_store_product5b","alt":"","position":1},{"id":2373,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:29:42","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:59:42","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:29:42","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:59:42","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product3b.jpg","name":"home_store_product3b","alt":"","position":2}],"attributes":[],"default_attributes":[],"variations":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0,"meta_data":[{"id":1705,"key":"_vc_post_settings","value":{"vc_grid_id":[]}},{"id":1760,"key":"slide_template","value":"default"}],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products\/70"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products"}]}},{"id":67,"name":"Ship Your Idea","slug":"ship-your-idea-3","permalink":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/product\/ship-your-idea-3\/","date_created":"2013-06-07T15:52:50","date_created_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:22:50","date_modified":"2013-06-07T15:52:50","date_modified_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:22:50","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","short_description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","sku":"","price":"15","regular_price":"15","sale_price":"","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"price_html":"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>15.00<\/span>","on_sale":false,"purchasable":true,"total_sales":0,"virtual":false,"downloadable":false,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"0.00","rating_count":0,"related_ids":[79,15,34,40,83],"upsell_ids":[22,40],"cross_sell_ids":[22,40],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":35,"name":"Ankle boots","slug":"ankle-boots"},{"id":37,"name":"Bags","slug":"bags-accessories"},{"id":49,"name":"Jackets","slug":"jackets"},{"id":52,"name":"Jeans","slug":"jeans-clothing-for-her-for-him"},{"id":32,"name":"Trainers","slug":"trainers"}],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":2380,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:39:37","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:09:37","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:39:37","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:09:37","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product6.jpg","name":"home_store_product6","alt":"","position":0},{"id":2381,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:39:38","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:09:38","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:39:38","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:09:38","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product6b.jpg","name":"home_store_product6b","alt":"","position":1},{"id":2369,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:26:07","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:56:07","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:26:07","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:56:07","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product1b.jpg","name":"home_store_product1b","alt":"","position":2}],"attributes":[],"default_attributes":[],"variations":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0,"meta_data":[{"id":1644,"key":"_vc_post_settings","value":{"vc_grid_id":[]}},{"id":1701,"key":"slide_template","value":""}],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products\/67"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products"}]}},{"id":60,"name":"Woo Logo","slug":"woo-logo-2","permalink":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/product\/woo-logo-2\/","date_created":"2013-06-07T15:42:55","date_created_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:12:55","date_modified":"2013-06-07T15:42:55","date_modified_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:12:55","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","short_description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","sku":"","price":"35","regular_price":"35","sale_price":"","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"price_html":"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>35.00<\/span>","on_sale":false,"purchasable":true,"total_sales":0,"virtual":false,"downloadable":false,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"4.00","rating_count":2,"related_ids":[34,53,15,50,22],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[15],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":41,"name":"Business Shoes","slug":"business-shoes"},{"id":45,"name":"Hats &amp; Caps","slug":"hats-caps"},{"id":52,"name":"Jeans","slug":"jeans-clothing-for-her-for-him"},{"id":57,"name":"Sandals","slug":"sandals"},{"id":58,"name":"Sandals","slug":"sandals-shoes"},{"id":63,"name":"Tops","slug":"tops"}],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":2382,"date_created":"2015-03-19T16:06:22","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:36:22","date_modified":"2015-03-19T16:06:22","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:36:22","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product7.jpg","name":"home_store_product7","alt":"","position":0},{"id":2383,"date_created":"2015-03-19T16:06:23","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:36:23","date_modified":"2015-03-19T16:06:23","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:36:23","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product7b.jpg","name":"home_store_product7b","alt":"","position":1},{"id":2370,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:28:16","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:16","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:28:16","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T11:58:16","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product2b.jpg","name":"home_store_product2b","alt":"","position":2}],"attributes":[],"default_attributes":[],"variations":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0,"meta_data":[{"id":1584,"key":"_vc_post_settings","value":{"vc_grid_id":[]}},{"id":1640,"key":"slide_template","value":""}],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products\/60"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/products"}]}},{"id":56,"name":"Ninja Silhouette","slug":"ninja-silhouette-2","permalink":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/product\/ninja-silhouette-2\/","date_created":"2013-06-07T15:37:19","date_created_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:07:19","date_modified":"2013-06-07T15:37:19","date_modified_gmt":"2013-06-07T11:07:19","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","short_description":"<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n","sku":"","price":"35","regular_price":"35","sale_price":"","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"price_html":"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&pound;<\/span>35.00<\/span>","on_sale":false,"purchasable":true,"total_sales":0,"virtual":false,"downloadable":false,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"in_stock":true,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":true,"average_rating":"4.17","rating_count":6,"related_ids":[50,40,83,19,37],"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[31],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":35,"name":"Ankle boots","slug":"ankle-boots"},{"id":36,"name":"Bags","slug":"bags"},{"id":45,"name":"Hats &amp; Caps","slug":"hats-caps"},{"id":48,"name":"Hoodies","slug":"hoodies"},{"id":50,"name":"Jackets","slug":"jackets-clothing-for-her-for-him"},{"id":51,"name":"Jeans","slug":"jeans"},{"id":57,"name":"Sandals","slug":"sandals"},{"id":59,"name":"Shorts","slug":"shorts"}],"tags":[],"images":[{"id":2384,"date_created":"2015-03-19T16:06:51","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:36:51","date_modified":"2015-03-19T16:06:51","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:36:51","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product8.jpg","name":"home_store_product8","alt":"","position":0},{"id":2385,"date_created":"2015-03-19T16:06:52","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:36:52","date_modified":"2015-03-19T16:06:52","date_modified_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:36:52","src":"https:\/\/diacogallery.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/home_store_product8b.jpg","name":"home_store_product8b","alt":"","position":1},{"id":2381,"date_created":"2015-03-19T15:39:38","date_created_gmt":"2015-03-19T12:09:38","date_modified":"2015-03-19T15:39:38","date_modified_gmt"...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newtonsoft Json Deserlize as C# Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277998/newtonsoft-json-deserlize-as-c-sharp-datagridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class Dimensions
{
    public string length { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created_gmt { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_modified_gmt { get; set; }
    public string src { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string alt { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
}

public class Self
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Collection
{
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    public List<Self> self { get; set; }
    public List<Collection> collection { get; set; }
}

...
```